# Slice a column or row from 2d Java Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to slice the columns or rows of a 2d Integer Array in `Java`.

I tried the following syntax `array[:][0] or array[0][:]` to get the first `column/row`. I get an error, so most probably this is not the correct syntax in Java. Is it possible to slice in any case a specific `column/row` in `Java`?

Comment: Where is that syntax from? Are you sure this is Java?

Comment: I would do something similiar in Python/numpy. I was asking if there is anything similiar in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, slicing in Python corresponds to extracting a subarray from the given array, so if you have an array like below:

```
int[][] vet = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Performing the following slicing `vet[0:3][1]` corresponds to retrieve an array with the elements `2, 5, 8` (second column from row 0 included to row 3 excluded).

Unfortunately, in Java this is not possible, at least not "vertically" since a 2D array is basically an array of arrays. Each "row" index identifies a sub-array but in reality there are now actual rows or columns, just arrays within another array.

What you could do is to use the `Arrays.copyOfRange()` method to slice an array "horizontally".

```
Integer[][] vet = new Integer[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Integer[] subArray = new Integer[3];
subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(vet[1], 0, 3); //Retrieves the elements [4, 5, 6]
```

Instead, for slicing "vertically" you need to write a utility method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] vet = new Integer[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    Integer[] subArray = new Integer[3];
    verticalSlicing(vet, subArray, 1, 0, 3);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArrayVert));  //Prints [2, 5, 8]
}

public static <T> void verticalSlicing(T[][] vet, T[] subArray, int col, int rowStart, int rowEnd) {
    if (col < 0 || col > subArray.length || (rowEnd - rowStart) > subArray.length) {
        return;
    }
    IntStream.range(rowStart, rowEnd).forEach(i -> subArray[i] = vet[i][col]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually a 2d array in java will look something like this:

```
double[][] doubleArray = new double[3][4];
```

So getting the first row can be:

```
double[] firstRow = doubleArray[0];
```

And getting the first column can look like this:

```
double[] firstColumn = new double[doubleArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < doubleArray.length; i++) {
  firstColumn[i] = doubleArray[i][0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you index array[x][y] you can get column x by:

```
int column[] = array[x].
```

To get row y:

```
int row[] = new int[array.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    row[i] = array[i][y];
}
```